# Hollow Be Thy Name

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, geography, music

[image: Hollow Be Thy Name]

Clues:

11100 0010 10000 0110 00111 00111 00111 00111 01010 00111 00111

y=-7x/17+14

[image of Bob Marley]

Instructions: Name That Deity

_ _ a _ _ _ _

Hint:

> -- .. --. .... - / .. / .-. . -.-. --- -- -- . -. -.. / ..- ... .. -. --. / -- --- .-. ... . / -.-. --- -.. .

Comment: Can you clarify - are there 4 clues, or 5?

Comment: @Astralbee Title = clue 1, string of numbers = clue 2, equation = clue 3, bob marley = clue 4, instructions = clue 5.

Comment: @Astralbee also the 7 blanks = clue 6

Comment: Your hint mentions to use Morse code, but can you at least hint as to where? I looked at the binary clue and switched the 1's for dots and 0's for dashes then vice-versa but the output does not seem intelligible.

Comment: @josephh try typing what you find in to google?

Comment: I did, but the strings 3Q1X777777 (1s as dot) with 8F6P2222222 (1s as dash) produce no google results that seem relevant. Maybe it's with spaces in between each two or three or four...characters? Another hint maybe? :(

Comment: @josephh Re-check your digits ;) You're on the right track!

Comment: Tyler. 8F6P2222+22 gives a GPS location in the Mediterranean sea (getting some good clues from this one...I think) and 3Q1X7777#77 gives nothing so I'm assuming the first one is somehow relevant. Also, the equation you have has a root (y=0) at x=34. So 34 has something to do with it. Is this getting closer? Or am I still way off?

Comment: Getting warmer! :)

Comment: The plus code coordinates are pretty much exactly x=34, y=14, but I can't figure out the next step.

Comment: @Skylar Is there a book that uses double-digit codes to find passages? Perhaps Bob Marley has something to do with it?

Comment: I had already suspected the answer to be "Jealous" days ago, from the x and y intercepts of the equation and Exodus being an album by Bob Marley and the Wailers! I kept thinking I must be wrong because there were more clues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answer

I believe the answer is

> Jealous

### Explanation

#### String of numbers

> For the string of 0s and 1s, as suggested in the comments, I converted 0s to dots and 1s to dashes (and vice versa). By decoding the Morse code, the results were `8F6P2222+22` and an invalid Morse code sequence.

#### Decoded string of numbers

> Having worked with plus codes before, I immediately recognized `8F6P2222+22` as a plus code. Plus codes are an addressing system made by Google that allows any location on Earth to receive a plus code with as much precision as needed. The code `8F6P2222+22` is located in the Mediterranean Sea, but that's not the important part. The coordinates are pretty much exactly x=34, y=14.

#### Equation

> For the equation clue, (34, 0) and (0, 14) were solutions, so the intercepts of the line it represents are at x=34 and y=14, which gave me confidence that my results from the previous paragraph were correct.

#### Bob Marley

> When I first discovered the numbers, I tried doing a web search for "34 14". I got a bunch of Bible verses, so I decided to try to figure out what book I should get the verse from. I looked through Bob Marley's discography, but I somehow missed the song called *Exodus*. After the OP hinted at the Bible in the comments, I checked again and I noticed it this time.

#### Instructions

> Exodus 34:14 ASV is *(for thou shalt worship no other god: for Jehovah, whose name is Jealous, is a jealous God)*. The instructions given in the puzzle are "Name That Deity", and the verse says that God's name is *Jealous*. This word fits the blanks in the final clue, `_ _ a _ _ _ _`, so I concluded it must be the answer.

#### Title

> *Hollow be Thy Name* is similar to *Hallowed be Thy Name*, a phrase from the Lord's Prayer in the Bible. Other than that, I don't know how else it might be related to the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer:

> BASIN? That's something hollow.

Because:

> I wondered if the puzzle was an *acrostic*.
>  **B**: Your first clue looks like **B**inary
>  **A**: The second seems to be **A**lgebra
>  **S**: Bob Marley was a **S**inger (ok I'm not 100% happy with this one)
>  **I**: So many deities to choose from but I couldn't help thinking of that Indiana Jones movie where he has to spell out **I**ehōva as the name of God.
>  **N**: And this is where I really begin to doubt myself because this could be hundreds of words that begin with any letter, but it could be **N**EATEST, among others.

Comment: ```_ _ a _ _ _ _```

Comment: @ACB So you're looking at the answer as fitting into the final clue with blanks. I saw that as an individual clue.